# I CANT GET RID OF: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver

I have tried everything, downloading the drivers and provided the exact path but i am getting stuck at the same point. I re installed Firefox but still the same error.
below is my code:

```
`!pip install selenium

import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.headless = True
binary_path  = r('C:\Users\Shefali\webdrivers\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + binary_path
service = Service(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Shefali\webdrivers\geckodriver.exe')
options.binary_location = binary_path
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)`
```

(and the error is : Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line)

i even tried :

```
options.binary_location = binary_path
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/Data")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)
```

but still the same. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You initialized the raw string literal incorrectly:

```py
r('C:\Users\Shefali\webdrivers\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
```

should be

```py
r'C:\Users\Shefali\webdrivers\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
```